# Firebase / Angularfire2: how to retrieve data when rules are managed by push ID?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

To retrieve data as a list in Angularfire2, we use the following code:

```
const queryList = af.database.list('/items');
```

But it is not possible to retrieve data when database security managed by **pushID** as described below:

```
{
    "rules": {
        “items”: {
            “$itemID”: {
                “.read”:condition
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Except querying firebase with pushID `(af.database.list('/items/pushID')` is there any other way to retrieve data?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your items in a list have security rules, that allow to everybody to read your data, then you can move `“.read”:true` one level higher and it will be possible to get all items with `af.database.list('/items')` request.

```
{
  "rules": {
     “items”: {
         “.read”:true
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: .Read = true was just an example. For sure I will not  put it in à real project . À comolex condition is used instead.